# Select distinct row based on 2 column values

Tags: distinct

I have table like

```
PONO    LINESNO   status
1        10        X
1        20        X
1        30        y 
2        10        X
2        20        X
2        30        X
```

Here in this table we have 2 unique PO numbers 1 and 2 which having 2 `LINESNO` on each `PO` with separate status.
I want to write a query to return only PO which all `LINESNO` have same status 
e.g if I pass Status in Where clause  "`Where Status='X'`" 
then it should return only one row  with PO 2 because `PO2` having all `LINESNO` same status with `X`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      PO NO
    </td>
    <td>
      LINENO
    </td>
    <td> Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 10 </td>
    <td> X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
    <td> X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 30 </td>
    <td> Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 10 </td>
    <td> X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
    <td> X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td> 30 </td>
    <td> X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show us the initial query you attempted or refine the question a bit more, it's kind of unclear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table pos (pono int, LINESNO int, status varchar(1));
insert into pos values (1, 10, 'x');
insert into pos values (1, 20, 'x');
insert into pos values (1, 30, 'y');
insert into pos values (2, 10, 'x');
insert into pos values (2, 20, 'x');
insert into pos values (2, 30, 'x');
insert into pos values (3, 20, 'x');
insert into pos values (3, 30, 'y');
insert into pos values (4, 30, 'x');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
Select a.pono, a.total_pono, b.total_status from
(select pono, count(*) as total_pono from pos group by pono) a,
(select pono, count(*) as total_status from pos where status = 'x' group by pono) b
where a.total_pono = b.total_status
and a.pono = b.pono;

| pono | total_pono | total_status |
| ---- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 2    | 3          | 3            |
| 4    | 1          | 1            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)